# Open Gallery in a Specific Directory

Tags: android, android-intent, gallery

I'm trying to open all the photos taken with my app using the native Gallery.

Here is my code:

```
Intent intentBrowseFiles = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intentBrowseFiles.setType("image/*");
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM/MyApp");
                    intentBrowseFiles.setData(uri); 
                    intentBrowseFiles.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intentBrowseFiles);
```

If I don't set the `setData` the gallery opens, but in the root, if I set, my app crashes.

Is there a way to open it in the Gallery in a specific directory?

Anyway, thank you!

Comment: Did you ever work out a solution? I'm starting to believe that you're simply not allowed to do this. I've tried doing something similar but all I get is a blank gallery screen.